# Regex to search double quoted strings on multiple lines

Tags: regular-expression

I am trying to write a regular expression that will match all double quoted strings across newlines. I have been fiddling around with the following pattern but it seems to only match strings on the same line.

```
/\v"\zs(.*|\n*)\ze"
```

The pattern should match something like this:

```
"This is an example
 of a multi, line -- %123 string with
 some random 123 symbol's 
 `inside` \\//><>< of it"
```

What is wrong with the pattern I have?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can simply use

```
/\v"([^"]|\n)*"
```

That is,

```
"       quotation mark
(...)*  followed by 0 or more of...
  [^"]    character that is not a quotation mark
  |\n     or a newline
"       followed by another quotation mark
```

This will also "work" for "multiple" strings "in the same" file, because `[^"]` makes sure that the regex never matches past another quotation mark.

---

Here's an alternative that's shorter but a bit harder to read:

```
/\v"\_.{-}"
```

Explanation:

```
"    quotation mark
\_.  any character, including a newline (see `:help /\_.')
{-}  non-greedy version of * (see `:help non-greedy')
"
```

This also works for multiple strings in the same file due to `{-}`, which is the lazy equivalent of `*`.

Comment: Thank you. For educational purposes, can you add how to do this without the use of `[^"]`?

Comment: @merb Sure, edited in an alternative that uses `\_.`.

Comment: Nice! Although perhaps one should improve slightly so as not to match escaped quotes?